# Delete value for previously assigned int field

Tags: java, null, integer

For example I made an integer `i`:

```
int i = 100;
```

Now I want to assign a value, as if I did:

```
int i;
```

What do I need to write in order to make my integer null (0 is not null)? `null` does not work for some reason.

Comment: You can't uninitialise a variable. You can set it to null, but it needs to be a reference type (such as `Integer`) instead of a primitive type (such as `int`).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I'm going to try initializing as an Integer type instead.